# Is input type="password" secure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i tried test of password input and I think it is not safe!

Why the passwords copy as plain text, and remain only stars (dots).

I have two inputs, first password and second text with same class

```
<input class="pass" type="password"/>
<input class="pass" type="text"/>
```

I tried write this js:

```
$(".pass").keyup(function(event) {
    $("." + $(this).attr("class")).not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

Check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rtyre3ay/1/)

What do you think?

Comment: Why would you think this was safe?

Comment: What do you even mean by "safe"?

Comment: All fields on the client are visible to the client. That's how the DOM works.

Comment: Pressing patterns on your keyboard is not safe.

Comment: I think copying the value insecure as plain text

Answer (score 5):

It is not secure. The purpose of the password field is just to make it harder for someone to look over your shoulder and see the password in clear text. 
Everything in the DOM is in clear text and not secure though.

Comment: so it is not hard to collect usernames and passwords, for example through an extension .. 
I think it is not good

Comment: @mandel99 How would you propose we perform validation on passwords (length, equality to another password field, existence of blocked characters etc.) if the value wasn't available as plain text via the DOM?

Comment: it's not about that is as plain text in the DOM but it appears as text instead of hide (dots) if you copied from input password

Comment: Yes, because you are copying the value (plain text, via the DOM) from a password field, which obfuscates the value, to a text field, which shows plain text. Javascript does not copy the rendered content of an input element, only the DOM value of it.

Answer (score 0):

This thing just make your password hidden while typing but not secure to trust it blindly as it will be saved as plain text. However if you have passwords stored somewhere on databases, you must use encryption to make them non-understandable if exposed.